# In shift reduce parsing why the handle always eventually appear on top of the stack and never inside?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

I was going through the text *Compilers Principles, Techniques and Tools* by *Ullman et. al* where I came across the excerpt where the authors try to justify why stack is the best data structure of shift reduce parsing. They said that it is so because of the fact that

[image: dagger] **"The handle will always eventually appear on top of the stack, never inside."**

**The Excerpt**

> This fact becomes obvious when we consider the possible forms of two successive steps in any rightmost derivation. These two steps can be of the form
>
> [image]
>
> In case (1), A is replaced by [image: betaBy], and then the rightmost nonterminal B in that right side is replaced by [image: gamma]. In case (2), A is again replaced first, but this time the right side is a string y of terminals only. The next rightmost nonterminal B will be somewhere to the left of y.
>
> Let us consider case (1) in reverse, where a shift-reduce parser has just reached the configuration
>
> [image]
>
> The parser now reduces the handle [image: gamma] to B to reach the configuration
>
> [image]
>
> in which [image: betaBy] is the handle, and it gets reduced to A
>
> In case (2), in configuration
>
> [image]
>
> the handle [image: gamma] is on top of the stack. After reducing the handle [image: gamma] to B, the parser can shift the string xy to get the next handle y on top of the stack,
>
> [image]
>
> Now the parser reduces y to A.
>
> In both cases, after making a reduction the parser had to shift zero or more symbols to get the next handle onto the stack. **It never had to go into the stack to find the handle. It is this aspect of handle pruning that makes a stack a particularly convenient data structure for implementing a shift-reduce parser.**

**My reasoning and doubts**

Intuitively this is how I feel that the statement in [image: dagger] can be justified

If there is an handle on the top of the stack, then the algorithm, will first reduce it before pushing the next input symbol on top of the stack. Since before the push any possible handle is reduced, so there is no chance of an handle being on the top of the stack and then pushing a new input symbol thereby causing the handle to go inside the stack.

Moreover I could not understand the logic the authors have given in highlighted portion of the excerpt justifying that the handle cannot occur inside the stack, based on what they say about B and other facts related to it.

Please can anyone help me understand the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to the logic expressed by the authors is in the statement at the beginning (emphasis added):

> This fact becomes obvious when we consider the possible forms of **two successive steps** in any rightmost derivation.

It's also important to remember that a bottom-up parser traces out a right-most derivation backwards. Each reduction performed by the parser is a step in the derivation; since the derivation is rightmost the non-terminal being replaced in the derivation step must be the last non-terminal in the sentential form. So if we write down the sequence of reduction actions used by the parser and then read the list backwards, we get the derivation. Alternatively, if we write down the list of productions used in the rightmost derivation and then read it backwards, we get the sequence of parser reductions.

Either way, the point is to prove that the successive handles in the derivation steps correspond to monotonically non-retreating prefixes in the original input. The authors' proof takes two derivation steps (any two derivation steps) and shows that the end of the handle of the second derivation step is not before the end of the handle of the first step (although the ends of the two handles may be at the same point in the input).

Comment: `monotonically non-retreating prefixes` could you please elaborate this term (which seems very difficult to me).

Comment: @abishek The lengths of the prefixes of the derived sentence which correspond to the successive handles are monotonically non-decreasing. That is, each one is at least as long as the previous one.

Comment: From your explanation : `Since B is the rightmost nonterminal in αβByz, the right end of  the handle of αβByz cannot occur inside the stack.` => since we are doing reverse of right derivation, so first the left most handle containing non terminals shall be reduced as a result of which the prefix of terminals shall go on increasing in each step. At the configuaration before that orange line, right end of the handle can be at most ending at B. But since no reduction takes places and based on the grammar we can push more symbols from the input to get new handle. (contd)

Comment: But if the situation arise that a right end of the handle occurs inside the stack after shift, then it is not possible, because otherwise, we could have performed this reduction, in the previous step only. So a contradiction,              Did I get the point?

Comment: @abishek I think you basically got this; it's not a complicated idea. The precision is only required if you want to write a formal proof.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Actually the language in the text is too precise and concise for a self learner to understand. ;(

Comment: But let me give you some advice. You don't learn how a parsing algorithm works by reading about it, nor by watching a video about it. At least, I don't. The only way to really understand -- if that's what you want -- is to grab a big piece of paper and a couple of coloured pens and do the algorithm yourself. Bottom-up parsing is way simpler than people seem to think ot is. It's just like running a DFA except that the parser keeps a stack recording its state history, so that itcan go back to (say) the third-last state.

Comment: It does that so that it can return to where it started the current production, and then do the transition again only this time with the reduced non-terminal.

Comment: That's all there is to it. But reading that is not nearly as useful as drawing the physical DFA and then moving a marker around it, as though it were a game of snakes and ladders.